# Identify this insect - genus, species (orange, black)

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Please help identify this insect - genus, species and anything interesting about it. Do the colors matter in the identification?

Note, this is [posted separately due to comments in this other thread](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/64042/can-you-identify-these-insects?noredirect=1#comment115250_64042).

[image][image]

Comment: Any idea where the species is from (country / type of ecosystem / ...)? Did you capture / find this insect yourself? What is its approximative size? (you can consider answering to these questions to your related posts as well)

Comment: i did not capture these - they were sent from the artist. i'll try asking, but not sure if they know where the original source image was from

Comment: The colours usually matter, but there can sometimes be variability within a species.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a Weevil. Specifically it looks like a red/orange-spotted lily weevil

[image]

Here is some more information on it:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachycerus_ornatus

though the information is very limited.

Comment: are they always colored like that?

Comment: its a general weevil. this one is just stopped but many arent spotted